# Cannot attach a Service Role Policy to a Customer Role. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: PolicyNotAttachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create role with AWS managed permission with role using cloudformation but I am getting an error:
`Cannot attach a Service Role Policy to a Customer Role. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: PolicyNotAttachable`. Any help would be appreciated

code snippet:

```
  AutoscalingRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AutoScalingServiceRolePolicy'
  ECSRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2008-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: ''
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole'

  ECSTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AmazonECSServiceRolePolicy'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you provided wrong ARN for manafed policy. I looked up for those in aws console and i got:

`arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole`

Instead of your:

`arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AmazonECSServiceRolePolicy`

Just go to IAM policy panel in AWS Console and find them one by one, the arn is provided for each.